# Drupal using a custom content type to populate a field in a second custom content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7 I would like to create 2 custom content types and link them together.

For example if I create the first content type of locations in the second content type of events I would have a location field that uses the location title from the first content type.

Ideally I would like to do this as a text input with autocomplete on it.

If that isn't possible can I add something like the chosen.js to make a large select easier to manage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module lets you reference nodes so you could choose which content types are selectable and have a drop down list of all instances of that content type: http://drupal.org/project/references

Comment: That looks very interesting thanks.

I'll have to install it and see how it goes.

Comment: Just got it installed and working. On first appearance it's exactly what I am after.

Comment: FYI References is pretty much deprecated in favour of [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

Comment: Thanks Clive I'll also have a look at Entity reference